# Adding a line of code to a text file with a .bat

Tags: text, batch-file

i am extrely novice at batch files but have been searching a way to add a line of text to a text file

the test file is called test.txt and all i need is the batch file to add a line of text at     the top of the file lets say "welcome" without over righting the file

```
how would i achieve this?
```

at the moment i have a install.bat that is blank and no text in the test.txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write "Welcome" in a new file, append the content of "test.txt" to that new file, and then rename the new file to "test.txt".

```
@echo off
echo Welcome > new.txt
echo. >> new.txt
type test.txt >> new.txt
copy /y new.txt test.txt
del new.txt
```

Comment: You can combine del+ren with a `copy /y new.txt test.txt`

Comment: @AlexK. True, I have updated my answer accordingly, thanks ;)

Comment: that is great many thanks :) but how do i add a blank line under welcome?

Comment: @thenashone Updated answer to add a blank line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Linux user, but in the past I had to deal with the limitations of Windows' command-line interpreter. I still do, occasionally. Anyway, here's my contribution:

```
@echo off
rem AddToTop - Add line to top of file
if [%2] == [] goto help
set file=%1
set line=%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
if exist %file% (
echo %line%>%file%.tmp
type %file%>>%file%.tmp
del %file%
rename %file%.tmp %file%
) else (
echo File "%file%" not found.
)
goto end
:help
echo Syntax: addtotop.bat file line
:end
```

Hope it helps. That's all I can do with this crappy CMD.EXE... ;-)